# Parse JSON and convert object back to JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I want to parse a nested JSON structure in Groovy. I would like to parse a sub element structure and then return the string in JSON format.

The Nested JSON structure:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "token": "test1",
    "url": "http://www.abc.to",
    "testsession":
    {
        "serverName": "0.0.0.0",
        "serverPort": 22,
        "remoteUsername": "admin",
        "remotePassword": "admin"
    },
    "deviceapp":
    {
        "repo": "abc-mvn-a-test-local",
        "path": "com/test\/test2\/test3\/mob",
        "platform": "ANDROID"
    }
}
```

my code below using JSONSlurper isn't quite giving me what i want:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
String deviceAppParsed = slurper.deviceapp
println "deviceAppParsed " + deviceAppParsed
// returns deviceAppParsed {repo=oxp-mvn-a-rel-local, path=com/nagra/opentv/experience/mob, platform=ANDROID}
def jsonDeviceApp = JsonOutput.toJson(deviceAppParsed)
println "IS IT JSON? " + jsonDeviceApp
// returns IS IT JSON "{repo=oxp-mvn-a-rel-local, path=com/nagra/opentv/experience/mob, platform=ANDROID}"
```

How can i parse the json to retrieve the nested deviceapp structure in raw JSON? Thanks.

: 
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
String deviceAppParsed = slurper.deviceapp
def jsonDeviceApp = JsonOutput.toJson(deviceAppParsed)

I expected println jsonDeviceApp to return:

```
{"repo": "abc-mvn-a-test-local","path": "com/test\/test2\/test3\/mob","platform": "ANDROID"}
```

instead it returned:

```
"{repo=oxp-mvn-a-rel-local, path=com/nagra/opentv/experience/mob, platform=ANDROID}"
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "isn't quite giving me what i want".   Show the results you are getting, the results that you expect, and what you've tried to explain the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace `String` to `def` in the following line:

```
String deviceAppParsed = slurper.deviceapp
```

by using string you are converting Object returned by `slurper.deviceapp` to string

should be:

```
def deviceAppParsed = slurper.deviceapp
```

in this case last line will print json

```
{"repo":"abc-mvn-a-test-local","path":"com/test/test2/test3/mob","platform":"ANDROID"}
```